# Defining worksheets and variables for mulitple worksheets for one textbox in VBA for cases

Tags: vba, excel, activex

I am having a problem with the block of code below. I am scanning a barcode which places the text in an ActiveX textbox. Upon seeing the text in the ActiveX text box, it runs through a series of cases. It then performs the necessary movements. My guess is that the textbox is in `Worksheet(1)`? Or that I do not know how to Dim a worksheeet or Set Variables properly!

I also know I will need to change the 0's to an actual possible cell range value.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

Dim bws As Worksheet, v, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l
Set bws = Worksheets("PACKAGING-BOXES")

Dim cws As Worksheet, v, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l
Set cws = Worksheets("PACKAGING-CARTONS")

Dim rws As Worksheet, v, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l
Set rws = Worksheets("Cut ROlls")

v = TextBox1.Value
a = 0
b = 0
c = 0
d = 0
e = 0
f = 0
g = 0
h = 0
i = 0
j = 0
k = 0
l = 0


'a = Packing Units in one case
'b = Clip strip, row reference, PACKAGING-CARTONS
'c = Clip strip hooks, row reference, PACKAGING-CARTONS
'd = Number of clip strips or hooks used, PACKAGING-CARTONS
'e =  row reference, PACKAGING-CARTONS
'f = Number of polybags used
'g = Carton Number, row reference, PACKAGING-CARTONS-WAYNE
'h = Box Number 1, row reference, PACKAGING-BOXES
'i = Box Number 2, row reference, PACKAGING-BOXES
'j = Box Number 3, row reference, PACKAGING-BOXES
'k = row ID for cut rolls
'l = number for case selection



'_____________________________________________________________________________________________
Select Case v

Case 1: l = 10


a = 72
b = 0
c = 0
d = 0
e = 0
f = 0
g = 97
h = 35
i = 36
j = 0
k = 1000





    'other cases here....
'_____________________________________________________________________________________________
End Select

'_____________________________________________________________________________________________


If l = 1 Then
'Packed Items (Packing Report)


    cws.Cells(b, 8) = cws.Cells(b, 8).Value - d
    cws.Cells(b, 8) = cws.Cells(b, 9).Value + d

    cws.Cells(c, 8) = cws.Cells(c, 8).Value - d
    cws.Cells(c, 9) = cws.Cells(c, 9).Value + d

    cws.Cells(e, 8) = cws.Cells(e, 8).Value - f
    cws.Cells(e, 9) = cws.Cells(e, 9).Value + f

    cws.Cells(g, 8) = cws.Cells(g, 8).Value - (a * cws.Cells(1, 1))
    cws.Cells(g, 9) = cws.Cells(g, 9).Value + (a * cws.Cells(1, 1))



    bws.Cells(h, 8) = bws.Cells(h, 8).Value - a
    bws.Cells(h, 9) = bws.Cells(h, 9).Value + a

    bws.Cells(i, 8) = bws.Cells(i, 8).Value - a
    bws.Cells(i, 9) = bws.Cells(i, 9).Value + a

    bws.Cells(j, 8) = bws.Cells(j, 8).Value - a
    bws.Cells(j, 9) = bws.Cells(j, 9).Value + a



    rws.Cells(k, 1) = cws.Cells(k, 1).Value + (a * cws.Cells(1, 1))




    TextBox1.Activate
    TextBox1.Value = ""


        End If


        End Sub
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Why are you declaring most of your variables (v, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l) multiple times, i.e. `Dim bws As Worksheet, v, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l` and `Dim cws As Worksheet, v, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l` and `Dim rws As Worksheet, v, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l`?  That will give a "duplicate declaration" error.

Comment: YowE3K, I have 3 inventory sheets. For example, If I scan item "A", it would take out items on three different worksheets using the same variable references. It's like scanning a finished case of inventory and taking out the item, box, carton, tray, ect for each case. I can combine all of the inventory sheets into one sheet and make it work, but I was wondering if it was possible to consolidate the variables under a "dim wb as workbook, v, a, ....." and then reference each sheet as  "Dim bws as worksheet"  "Set bws = wb.Worksheets("PACKAGING-BOXES")" I keep getting a subscript out of range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, this needs to be the start of the code. Needs to have the Wb defined as variables instead of each sheet :)

> ```
> Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
> ```

```
Dim wb As Workbook, v, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l
Set wb = Workbooks("Inventory Tracking.xlsm")


Dim bws As Worksheet
Set bws = wb.Worksheets("PACKAGING-BOXES")

Dim cws As Worksheet
Set cws = wb.Worksheets("PACKAGING-CARTONS")

Dim rws As Worksheet
Set rws = wb.Worksheets("Cut Rolls")

Dim fws As Worksheet
Set fws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

v = TextBox1.Value
a = 0
b = 0
c = 0
d = 0
e = 0
f = 0
g = 0
h = 0
i = 0
j = 0
k = 0
l = 0
```